# Extract common part of images with Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, difference, opencv-features2d

I'm writing a program that find differences between images. For now, I'm finding features with AKAZE, so I've the common point of the 2 images. The problem is that these 2 images have only a part in common. How can I extract the common part from both images? For better explanation: I need to extract the common part from the first image and then from the second, so I can do `absdiff` for finding difference.
I'm programming in c++

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *warp* the first image onto the second. You can use `findHomography` and `perspectiveTransform` functions given by the correspondence of your keypoints. You can find most of the code you need [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html).

Update

---

Incidentally, I had to do basically the same stuff today. It's tested on gray images (`Mat1b`), but should require only minor changes to apply to rgb images (`Mat3b`).
Here the relevant parts of the code:

```
Mat1b A = imread("...");
Mat1b B = imread("...");

vector<Point2f> ptsA; 
vector<Point2f> ptsB;

// Fill ptsA, ptsB with the points given by the match of your descriptors.

Mat H = findHomography(ptsA, ptsB, CV_RANSAC); // With ransac is more robust to outliers

Mat1b warpedA;
warpPerspective(A, warpedA, H, B.size());

// Now compute diff
Mat1b res;
absdiff(warpedA, B, res);

// res is what you are looking for!
```

Comment: I'll give a try and let you know!

Comment: I've tried but it does not work. How can I crop out the similar part? I've seen that `Mat()` takes as input a Rect, while with `perspectiveTransform` I get 4 point. How can I use that points to crop out image?

Comment: @Dp89 Look at [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#cv.WarpPerspective)

Comment: @Dp89 updated the answer with a piece of code, might be helpful ;D

Comment: I had the same solution by myself :P (what a coincidence!). One last question: what happens if there's no common part between two images?

Comment: It should crash! So be sure that `ptsA` and `ptsB` size is at least 4 (minimum number of corresponding points to compute the homography).

Comment: Ok. I've asked that because in my program I can't assume that there's a common part, so I've to manage that case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Miki Very nice solution! The result is B picture with black rect as intersection. But (1) is there a way to get just coordinates of this rect? Or to (2) get compound picture of A and B?

Comment: @alex I can't help you now... To get a proper answer I recommend to ask a new question with a clear problem statement