# Get coordinates of images intersection with OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, intersection

In this answer described how to get picture from two images so intersection (common part of them) will be coloured black — https://stackoverflow.com/a/31258083/4767232

How can I get this result not as picture but **as a rect** (e.g. left=100, top=50, bottom=200, right=300)?

Comment: I don't know if you can get from `warpPerspective` pure rect with parameters (height, width, x, y) because of angle. You can find on mask max contours, and this will be your left, top, bottom and right corner. You can also using Harris Corner Detection on mask for get 4 corners.

Answer (score 0):

The position of intersection can be obtained by transforming zero point by the `H` matrix.

```
val p0 = MatOfPoint2f(org.opencv.core.Point(0.0, 0.0))
val result = Mat()
Core.transform(p0, result, H)
```

(and getting size of the rect is trivial)